# android backup agent and SherlockMapActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-backup-service, actionbarsherlock-map

I try to implement a Backup Agent in my Android app, and I've got a weird issue every times it restore (at first launch) :

```
Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockMapActivity; (916)
Link of class 'Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockMapActivity;' failed
Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/myapp/activity/impl/MapActivity; (674)
Link of class 'Lnet/myapp/activity/impl/MapActivity;' failed
Could not find class 'net.myapp.activity.impl.MapActivity', referenced from method net.myapp.helper.SlidingMenuHelper.<clinit>

VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1520 (Lnet/myapp/activity/impl/MapActivity;) in Lnet/myapp/helper/SlidingMenuHelper;
VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0081
     Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lnet/myapp/helper/SlidingMenuHelper;
```

Complete log here : https://gist.github.com/romainguefveneu/1acc78cabbed65fba4b7

The restore process works just fine, when I open a second time the app, my data are correctly restored.

It seems to be an issue with the loading of SherlockMapActivity, I use all those libs in my project :

- actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.2.0.jar
- bugsense-3.0.1.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- gson-2.2.2.jar
- joda-time-2.1.jar
- ocpsoft-pretty-time-1.0.7.jar

Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: I just saw your post. I have exactly the same issue as posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505996/android-data-backup-service Did you find a solution?